# BigQuery: Comments at top of the query while creating a view

Tags: google-bigquery, comments

I need to know why when I create a view any comment before the "SELECT" statement is ignored.
Do you know if this is an intended behavior?

I know I can use a bk command, concatenate the comment with python or update the view on the UI.
I only need to know if ignoring the comments before "SELECT" statement is an intended behavior.